# Boost Graph Library - Dijkstra's shortest path fails when the edge weights are large?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I have a question regarding the edge weights when using Dijkstra's algorithm in Boost. The problem I am facing is that when the edge weights are large, I do not get a solution from Dijkstra's algorithm.

Let's say I have an adjacency list with bundled properties. My vertices are of type VertexType and edges are of type EdgeType. Here, VertexType resembles a person for a simple example. VertexType::pred is the predecessor when used with Dijkstra's algorithm.

```
struct VertexType
{
    std::string name;
    int age;
    int pred;
};

struct EdgeType
{
    double weight;
};
```

Below is a simple example.

```
void edgeWeightProblem()
{
    // Graph and vertex descriptor typedefs.
    typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS,
            boost::directedS,
            VertexType,
            EdgeType
            > GraphType;
    typedef boost::graph_traits<GraphType>::vertex_descriptor VertexDescriptor;

    // Create graph and vertices vector.
    GraphType G;
    std::vector<VertexDescriptor> graphVertices;

    // Add vertices.
    graphVertices.push_back(add_vertex({"Tom", 23}, G));
    graphVertices.push_back(add_vertex({"Frank", 25}, G));
    graphVertices.push_back(add_vertex({"John", 42}, G));
    graphVertices.push_back(add_vertex({"Emily", 22}, G));

    // Add edges.
    add_edge(graphVertices[0], graphVertices[1], {.2564}, G);
    add_edge(graphVertices[0], graphVertices[2], {.3572}, G);
    add_edge(graphVertices[1], graphVertices[3], {.1246}, G);
    add_edge(graphVertices[2], graphVertices[3], {.5361}, G);

    // Dijkstra shortest path.
    dijkstra_shortest_paths(G, graphVertices.front(),
        predecessor_map(boost::get(&VertexType::pred, G))
        .distance_map(boost::get(&VertexType::pred, G))
        .weight_map(boost::get(&EdgeType::weight, G)));

    // Debug pred.
    std::vector<VertexType> vec;
    for (const VertexDescriptor& vd : graphVertices)
    {
        vec.push_back(G[vd]);
    }

    // Extract the shortest path.
    std::vector<VertexDescriptor> shortestPath;
    VertexDescriptor currentVertex = graphVertices.back();
    while (currentVertex != graphVertices.front())
    {
        shortestPath.push_back(currentVertex);
        currentVertex = G[currentVertex].pred;
    }
    shortestPath.push_back(currentVertex);
    std::reverse(shortestPath.begin(), shortestPath.end());

    // Display graph.
    std::cout << "\nGraph Display: \n";
    boost::print_graph(G);
    std::cout << "\n";

    // Print the shortest path.
    std::cout << "Shortest Path: \n";
    for (const auto& node : shortestPath)
    {
        std::cout << node << " -> ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

As expected, I get the following output:

```
Graph Display:
0 --> 1 2
1 --> 3
2 --> 3
3 -->

Shortest Path:
0 -> 2 -> 3 ->
```

**But, if I remove the decimal of the edge weights, (ex: .2564 -> 2564), I will not be able to find the shortest path since the predecessor of each vertex will be itself. This also result in an infinite loop as a side affect for this example.**

You can see this by placing a breakpoint after the "Debug pred" section and inspecting "vec". What is going on here? I assume this is a misunderstanding of Boost as I am quite new to it.

I have tried to play around with the weights, but it seems once the weights are larger, this issue happens. These weights are not so large that overflow should be a consideration, so I am quite confused as to what is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing `pred` as both the predecessor map *and* the distance map. One will overwrite the other at unspecified points during algorithm execution. The result is unspecified at best, [undefined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) if you're lucky.

Fixed that and simplified some of the code, now the result is the same for both weight inputs:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/401ef86511cfd217)**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/dag_shortest_paths.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

struct VertexType {
    std::string name;
    int         age;
    size_t      pred;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, VertexType const& vt) {
        return os << "{" << std::quoted(vt.name) << ", " << vt.age << ", pred:" << vt.pred << "}";
    }
};

struct EdgeType {
    double weight;
};

int main() {
    // Graph and vertex descriptor typedefs.
    using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, VertexType, EdgeType>;
    using V     = Graph::vertex_descriptor;

    // Create graph and vertices vector.
    Graph g;

    // Add vertices.
    V v0 = add_vertex({"Tom", 23, 0}, g);
    V v1 = add_vertex({"Frank", 25, 0}, g);
    V v2 = add_vertex({"John", 42, 0}, g);
    V v3 = add_vertex({"Emily", 22, 0}, g);

    // Add edges.
    add_edge(v0, v1, {2564}, g);
    add_edge(v0, v2, {3572}, g);
    add_edge(v1, v3, {1246}, g);
    add_edge(v2, v3, {5361}, g);

    auto bundle    = get(boost::vertex_bundle, g);
    auto pred      = get(&VertexType::pred, g);
    auto weight    = get(&EdgeType::weight, g);
    auto distances = std::vector<double>(num_vertices(g));

    // Dijkstra shortest path.
    auto src = v0;
    dijkstra_shortest_paths(g, src,
                            predecessor_map(pred)
                            .distance_map(distances.data())
                            .weight_map(weight));

#if 0
    // Debug pred.
    std::vector<VertexType> vertex_properties;
    for (auto vd : boost::make_iterator_range(vertices(g))) {
        vertex_properties.push_back(g[vd]);
    }
#endif

    // Extract the shortest path.
    std::deque<V> path;
    for (V cur = num_vertices(g) - 1;; cur = pred[cur]) {
        path.push_front(cur);
        if (cur == src || cur == pred[cur])
            break;
    }

    // Display graph.
    print_graph(g, bundle, std::cout << "Graph Display: \n");

    // Print the shortest path.
    std::cout << "\nShortest Path: ";
    for (const auto& vd : path) std::cout << (vd == src ? "" : " -> ") << vd;

    std::cout << "\nWhich is: ";
    for (const auto& vd : path) std::cout << (vd == src ? "" : " -> ") << g[vd];
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
Graph Display:
{"Tom", 23, pred:0} --> {"Frank", 25, pred:0} {"John", 42, pred:0}
{"Frank", 25, pred:0} --> {"Emily", 22, pred:1}
{"John", 42, pred:0} --> {"Emily", 22, pred:1}
{"Emily", 22, pred:1} -->

Shortest Path: 0 -> 1 -> 3
Which is: {"Tom", 23, pred:0} -> {"Frank", 25, pred:0} -> {"Emily", 22, pred:1}
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot for the help! After looking at this I'm pretty amazed my original code worked at all. I am guessing the only reason my original solution worked at all with the smaller weights is because when the distance would be narrowed from double to int, it would result in 0 or 1, which could have gave the same solution with a small problem like this. Either way, it is undefined and thanks for finding the problem!